# How to group an array of objects by key and sums a nested object property

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, grouping, lodash

I have an array of product objects, each product contains the product price besides a nested object representing the currency used.

```
var products = [
{
    'id': '1',
    'currency': { id:1, name:'Dollar' },
    'price': '100'
}, {
    'id': '4',
    'currency': { 
        id:2, 
        name:'Euro',
        current_quotation: {
           date: '2020-03-02',
           quotation: 68
        } 
    },
    'price': '300'
}, {
    'id': '6',
    'currency': { id:1, name:'Dollar' },
    'price': '50'
}, {
    'id': '16',
    'currency': null,
    'price': '50'
}, {
    'id': '23',
    'currency': { id:2, name:'Euro' },
    'price': null
}
];
```

What I'm trying to do is to get an array with a unique object per currency with its price sum, preferably using lodash or ES6 script. What I need as a result is:

```
var subtotals = [
    {currency:'Dollar', total: 150},
    {currency:'Euro', total: 300}
]
```

I tried with many samples but no luck so far. My approach is this, but it's returning the whole product object within the array, which is so far from expected result

```
let subtotals = state.products.reduce((h, product) => Object.assign(h, { [product.currency?.name]:( h[product.currency?.name] || [] ).concat({currency: product.currency?.name, price: product.price}) }), {})
```

Result

```
{
    "Euro":[
        {"currency":"Euro","price":"300"}
    ],
    "Dolar":[
        {"currency":"Dolar","price":"100"},
        {"currency":"Dolar","price":"50"}
    ]
}
```

**Please note that some products may have no currency at the begining since it value comes from a dropdown input. In that case the value can be ommited in the result.**

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I've edited the code, just a typo. I need to sum the objects with the same currency, no subtractions at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using lodash, you can group by the currency object's `name` property using `_.groupBy()`. And then map the result object to an array of objects. The object which you map to can use the key as the currency and the summed total of the grouped array (using `_.sumBy()`) as the total:

```js
const products = [ { 'id': '1', 'currency': { id:1, name:'Dollar' }, 'price': '100' }, { 'id': '4', 'currency': { id:2, name:'Euro' }, 'price': '300' }, { 'id': '6', 'currency': { id:1, name:'Dollar' }, 'price': '50' }, { 'id': '16', 'currency': null, 'price': '50' }, { 'id': '23', 'currency': { id:2, name:'Euro' }, 'price': null } ];

const getSubTotals = p => _.flow(
  products => _.filter(products, o => _.has(o, p)),
  sm_prod => _.groupBy(sm_prod, p),
  gr => _.map(gr, (arr, currency) => ({currency, total: _.sumBy(arr, ({price}) => +price)}))
);

console.log(getSubTotals('currency.name')(products));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

**EDIT** As you have changed your question. You'll need to use some alternate code to get your desired result:

```js
const products = [ { 'id': '1', 'currency': { id:1, name:'Dollar' }, 'price': '100' }, { 'id': '4', 'currency': { id:2, name:'Euro', current_quotation: { date: '2020-03-02', quotation: 68 } }, 'price': '300' }, { 'id': '6', 'currency': { id:1, name:'Dollar' }, 'price': '50' }, { 'id': '16', 'currency': null, 'price': '50' }, { 'id': '23', 'currency': { id:2, name:'Euro' }, 'price': null } ];

const getSubTotals = p => products => {
  const _gr = _(products).filter(o => _.has(o, p)).groupBy(p);
  const quote_map = _gr.mapValues((arr, k) => _.sumBy(arr, o => _.get(o, 'currency.current_quotation.quotation', 0)) || 1).value();
  const _totals = _gr.map((arr, currency) => ({currency, total: _.sumBy(arr, ({price}) => +price)}));
  return _totals.map(({currency, total, ...r}) => ({currency, total, quote_total: total*quote_map[currency]})).value();
}


console.log(getSubTotals('currency.name')(products));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Really nice approach, any way to ignore those objects with null currency object or null/0  price? It's returning an array object `{currency:"undefined",total:123456}` when it happens.

Comment: @Luciano you could filter out any objects which don't have the `currency.name` property (prices with `null` will be treated as `0` due to unary plus operator `+price`)

Comment: Assuming that product.currency can also contain (or not) a nested object "current_quotation" with a "quotation" property inside, how can I return an additional property from getSubTotals() as the result of (total * currency.current_quotation.quotation) ? Is that possible?

Comment: In addition, if no current_quotation object exists the additional property  should be the same as total property value

Comment: @Luciano I modified my code to add an additional property which holds the `total * currency.current_quotation.quotation`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you want to sum up the totals and get a Euro total of 300:

Iterate over each `currency.name` and `price`, transforming the input into an object whose keys are the currency names and values are the cumulative price for that currency name found so far. At the end, map the object's entries to get an array of objects of your desired format:

```js
var products = [
  {
      'id': '1',
      'currency': { id:1, name:'Dollar' },
      'price': '100'
  }, {
      'id': '4',
      'currency': { id:2, name:'Euro' },
      'price': '300'
  }, {
      'id': '6',
      'currency': { id:1, name:'Dollar' },
      'price': '50'
  }
];

const pricesByName = {};
for (const { currency: { name }, price } of products) {
  pricesByName[name] = (pricesByName[name] || 0) + Number(price);
}
const output = Object.entries(pricesByName)
  .map(([currency, total]) => ({ currency, total }));
console.log(output);
```

If the currency or price is null, ignore them using an `if` statement:

```js
var products = [
{
    'id': '1',
    'currency': { id:1, name:'Dollar' },
    'price': '100'
}, {
    'id': '4',
    'currency': { id:2, name:'Euro' },
    'price': '300'
}, {
    'id': '6',
    'currency': { id:1, name:'Dollar' },
    'price': '50'
}, {
    'id': '16',
    'currency': null,
    'price': '50'
}, {
    'id': '23',
    'currency': { id:2, name:'Euro' },
    'price': null
}
];

const pricesByName = {};
for (const { currency, price } of products) {
  if (price === null || currency === null) continue;
  const { name } = currency;
  pricesByName[name] = (pricesByName[name] || 0) + Number(price);
}
const output = Object.entries(pricesByName)
  .map(([currency, total]) => ({ currency, total }));
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Looks good, but it fails when a product has no currency object. Please note that some products may have no currency object in the first instance. This code is in fact used in a vuex getter which will be mutating while the user fills out a form, so the price could be also 0 or an empty value

Comment: All of the objects in your example input have such an object. What sort of logic would you want when there's no object, would you want to just not do anything on that iteration?

Comment: I've edited the code once again, sorry for the sloppiness. Those objects containing a null currency object or a null price can be ignored in the result since they won't affect the sum.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this up in the console and it should work for your case:

```
var products = [
    {
        id: '1',
        currency: { id: 1, name: 'Dollar' },
        price: '100',
    },
    {
        id: '4',
        currency: { id: 2, name: 'Euro' },
        price: '300',
    },
    {
        id: '6',
        currency: { id: 1, name: 'Dollar' },
        price: '50',
    },
];

subtotals = {};

products.map(x => {
    if(x.currency !== null){
        subtotals[x.currency.name] === undefined
            ? (subtotals[x.currency.name] = parseInt(x.price))
            : (subtotals[x.currency.name] += parseInt(x.price));
    }
});
```